# Matplotlib: using colormap to show regime (axvspan or bar?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to represent one dataset as blocks of color in my plot (instead of showing as a variable width bar chart i would like to show this as a variable width block with a background color.)

I could do something like this:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors        

# Create fake data
x = numpy.linspace(0,4)
y = numpy.exp(x)

# Now plot one by one
bar_width = x[1] - x[0]  # assuming x is linealy spaced
for pointx, pointy in zip(x,y):
    point = 40
    current_color = cm.jet( min(pointy/30, 30)) # maximum of 30
    plt.bar(pointx, point, bar_width, color = current_color)       

plt.show()
```

But then i do not have scaling of the colormap to the extent of my data.

Or i could do something like:

```
for i in range(10):
    color = cm.jet(min(i/30, 30))
    plt.axvspan(i, i+1, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5)
```

But again this is unsatisfactory as i would like to have a way to have my data autoscaled to cmap's min and max.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the 'extent of your data' I assume you mean that the colour map maxes out for `pointy>30`. This can easily be solved by simplifying your `current_color`:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors        

# Create fake data
x = numpy.linspace(0,4)
y = numpy.exp(x)

# Now plot one by one
bar_width = x[1] - x[0]  # assuming x is linealy spaced
max_y = y.max()
min_y = y.min()

for pointx, pointy in zip(x,y):
    point = 40
    current_color = cm.jet((pointy - min_y)/(max_y - min_y))
    plt.bar(pointx, point, bar_width, color = current_color)       

plt.show()
```

Before, once `pointy` was greater than 30 the value given to `cmap.jet` was greater than unity which is an upper threshold for the color map. Instead we find the range of y, then find the fraction of the way through this range that `pointy` is and pass that number (between 0 and 1) to the color map.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you are looking for, but I think a few of your questions can be answered by using a scaled cmap, from `cm.get_cmap`. We can scale the the range of your data from 0,1 and plug it into the cmap. I made the bars have different widths by simply plotting multiple bar charts, there may be a better matplotlib library call to do this in one-shot.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Create fake data
X = numpy.linspace(0,4)
Y = numpy.exp(X)

# Pick a cmap
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet')

for x0,x1 in zip(Y,Y[1:]):
    c = cmap((x0-Y.min())/Y.max())
    plt.bar([x0,],1.0,x1-x0,
            color=c,
            linewidth=0)
plt.xlim(Y.min(),Y.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]